# From character to interger in a list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply, tibble

Let's say that my data is the following:

```
one<-tibble(a= 1:3, 
   b=c("N/A", 0, 5), 
   c=c("n/e", 6, 7))

two<-tibble(x= 1:3, 
   y=c("N/A", 0, 5), 
   z=c("n/e", 6, 7))

three<-tibble(x= 1:3, 
          y=6:8, 
          z=0:2)

MyList<-list(one, two, three, two)
```

As you can see some of my tibbles have characters which i will convert in NA using

```
MyList<-map(MyList, ~mutate_all(., funs(replace(., .== "n/e", NA))))
MyList<-map(MyList, ~mutate_all(., funs(replace(., .== "N/A", NA))))
```

I want to convert the chr columns (2 and 3) into int columns. I am using

```
lapply(MyList, as.numeric)
```

or

```
lapply(1:length(MyList), function(x) as.numeric(MyList[[x]][2]))
```

However, i have the following error:

> Error in lapply(MyList, as.numeric) :
> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` way would be -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

MyList <- map(MyList, function(x) x %>%
      mutate(across(.fns = ~as.numeric(replace(.x, .x %in% c('N/A', 'n/e'), NA)))))

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      a     b     c
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    NA    NA
#2     2     0     6
#3     3     5     7

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    NA    NA
#2     2     0     6
#3     3     5     7

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     6     0
#2     2     7     1
#3     3     8     2

#[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    NA    NA
#2     2     0     6
#3     3     5     7
```

and in base R -

```
MyList <- lapply(MyList, function(x) {
  x[] <- lapply(x, function(y) 
    as.numeric(replace(y, y %in% c('N/A', 'n/e'), NA)))
  x
})
```